# How to pass data from failed child worker to last worker in chain with android CoroutineWorkers

Tags: android, android-workmanager

My current android application employs chained workers to perform complex background tasks.

Im observing only the last worker in the chain to detect whether or not the complete chain has completed successfully. This approach has been acceptable till now, as I have a new requirement where I need to also pass data when a worker fails.

is my only option to start observing all workers in the chain?

or

is it possible to set output data in a failing child worker and access it from the workinfo obtained from observing the last worker in the chain?

for example if i have a chain of 5 sequential workers as follows:-

```
WorkerA
WorkerB
WorkerC
WorkerD
WorkerZ
```

I am only observing `WorkerZ`, and `WorkerC` fails and sets outputData in its result, is there any way I can access that WorkData from observing only `WorkerZ`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to observe all the workers. If you are returning data with `Result.failure` in each worker, you can easily find which worker failed and what was its output data like this:

```
 WorkManager.getInstance(context)
        .getWorkInfosForUniqueWorkLiveData(UNIQUE_WORK_NAME)
        .observeForever { workInfos ->
            if(it.state == WorkInfo.State.FAILED){ //failed worker
                  val failureResult = it.outputData
            }
        }
```

or like this:

```
val failureResult = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
        .getWorkInfosForUniqueWork(UNIQUE_WORK_NAME)
        .get()
        .firstOrNull{
            it.state == WorkInfo.State.FAILED
        }
        ?.outputData
```

Comment: this approach looks a good candidate, however there are numerous cases where it does not work as required. such as when exiting and re entering the app, also once multiple occurences of the same unique work have executed and failed (or not) the observer receives the already processed workInfos

Comment: These two cases you mentioned are different matters. For the first case, the `getWorkInfosForUniqueWork` function returns a `LiveData` and it's up to you how you observe it. For example you can use `observeForever` or observe it using a `lifeCycleOwner` and handle exiting and re entering the app.

Comment: As for second case you can use different values instead of `UNIQUE_WORK_NAME` and observe the result for the chain you want.